# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix' is the error

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

[image]

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix' is the error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61031352/9524424

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your code used to work and now it doesn't because you updated your `pandas` package.

If you check `pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix`'s [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) you will see that this method has been [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation).

Instead, you should use:

`X_mat = X[['height', 'width']].values()`